# Finding all possible routes through reccursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

So I have been working at this for way to long and just can not seem to fix this. I have a list of "roads" that have a startCity and goalCity. Through recursion I have to find all possible routes. My current code is only finding the longest route. 
What can I do to fix this?

Roads:

```
Colorado Springs,Denver
Denver,Loveland
Loveland,Fort Collins
Loveland,Greeley
Greeley,Fort Collins
Fort Collins,Cheyenne
Fort Collins,Laramie
Laramie,Cheyenne
```

Current Output:

```
    All paths from Colorado Springs to Fort Collins are:
 1. [Colorado Springs, Denver, Loveland, Fort Collins]
 2. [Colorado Springs, Denver, Loveland, Greeley, Fort Collins]
 3. [Colorado Springs, Denver, Loveland, Greeley, Fort Collins, Loveland, Greeley, Fort Collins]
```

EDIT UPDATED CODE:
Now I am getting extra output...

```
    public ArrayList<String> findPath2(String startCity, String goalCity, String oStartCity, ArrayList<String> route){

    //see if goal city possible
    if(tester(goalCity) != true){
        return null;
    }

    ///Base Case////
    if(startCity.equals(goalCity)){
        route.add(goalCity);
        String derp = route.toString();
        paths.add(derp);
        System.out.println(derp);
        //return route;
    }else{
        for (int i = 0; i < theRoads.size(); i ++){
            if(theRoads.get(i).isFrom(startCity)){


                route.add(startCity);
                findPath2(theRoads.get(i).endsAt(), goalCity, oStartCity, route);

                //System.out.println(route);
                //course = startCity + " -> " + course;

                for (int l = i+1; l < theRoads.size(); l ++){
                    if(theRoads.get(l).isFrom(startCity) && !(theRoads.get(l).startsAt().equals(goalCity))){
                        System.out.println("SPLIT");

                        route.remove(goalCity);
                        findPath2(theRoads.get(l).endsAt(), goalCity, oStartCity, route);
                        System.out.println("SPLIT RETURNING");

                    }
                }

                //return route;
            }
        }
    }
    return route;
}
```

Also all of my code if anyone is interested:
http://pastebin.com/3yeBU2fn

2ND EDIT: @Vandale

Still cant get it to work but something like this?

```
public ArrayList<String> findPath2(String startCity, String goalCity, ArrayList<String> route){

        ArrayList<String> course = new ArrayList<>();

        if(startCity.equals(goalCity)){
            course.add(startCity);
        }else{
            route.add(startCity);
            for (int i = 0; i < theRoads.size(); i ++){
                if(theRoads.get(i).isFrom(startCity)){

                    for (int l = 0; l < route.size(); l ++){
                        //check if city has already been visited && if its possible to get to goal city (not sure if this works)
                        if(!(route.get(l).equals(startCity)) && (findPath2(theRoads.get(l).endsAt(), goalCity, route).equals(goalCity))){

                            course.add(startCity + "->" + findPath2(theRoads.get(l).endsAt(), goalCity, route));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            route.remove(startCity);
        }
        System.out.println(course);
        return course;
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `return "null";` seems a bit strange - do you really want to return a string?

Comment: For starters, you are going to need to return a `List<String>`, and not a `String`.

Comment: yeah I didn't mean to do that, apparently works both ways though.

Comment: Why do you need to use recursion? That may not be the most efficient way to go.

Comment: @Koen You cannot find longest path, nor all paths without some simulation of recursion.

Comment: It is a requirent to use recursion unfortunately.

Comment: Well, I would use some kind of "to do"-list combined with an achievement list. That way true recursion (with function call overhead) can be avoided.

Comment: @Koen That is going to involve a custom stack, that is most likely less optimized than the machine stack, but it is a micro optimization anyway

Comment: Anyway, you have to keep track of which cities were reached in how many hops (or miles or whatever), in order to be able to decide which paths should no longer be followed.

Comment: I thought with the code i had it would create a path till it hit a road that "split" two roads that have the same start city. (Say left and right at the split) I thought my code would hit the split then create two separate recursive calls, one going left (the shorter path) and one going right. Both using the same path created before the split, and then just adding whatever path they came up with after the split.

Comment: What constraints are there on the list of roads? Are all roads bi-directional? Could you have cycles in the roads (road from a to b, b to c, and c to a)? Can you use the same road only once? Also what does `tester` do I am fairly sure that it's redundant to be calling it every time.

Comment: The roads are one directional, i can only start from the startCity and travel one direction, but two roads may have the same startCity, from there i have to check both roads to see if they reach the destination.  tester is just to check if the goalCity is even in the list of roads. I suppose i can move that to a different location so it doesn't get called repetitivly.

Answer (score 0):

`oStartCity` is never actually used in the body of your method so you can get rid of it.

One way to do it is as follow

```
Create empty list of paths
if at target city
    add current city to paths
else
    add current city to list of visited cities
    for each city connected to this
        if not already visited city and city has path to the target city
            add current city + each one of connected cities paths to paths
    remove current city from list of visited cities
return paths
```

In order to keep track of what cities you already visited, you should use something like a `HashSet`, which should be passed in as an argument to the function.

One thing to note is that if there are no paths to the destination city, then the function will return an empty list, which you can use to check to see if there any paths. If you use this, you shouldn't need the call to tester.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, hopefully this helps someone in the future!

```
public void findAllPaths(String startCity, String goalCity){
        clearPaths();
        findPathHelps(startCity, goalCity, "");
    }

    private void findPathHelps(String startCity, String goalCity, String path){
        //base
        if(startCity.equals(goalCity))
            paths.add(path + goalCity);
        //cycle through
        for(Road road : this.roads)
            if(road.isFrom(startCity))
                //recursion and stuff
            findPathHelps(road.endsAt(), goalCity, path+startCity+"->");
    }
```